# Multiple bridge interfaces have only 1 IP

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

Not sure what I'm missing but I've set up 2 bridges over 2 different dummy interfaces as follows:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------#

## VIRBR10 ##

auto virbr10-dummy
iface virbr10-dummy inet manual
    pre-up /sbin/ip link add virbr10-dummy type dummy
    up /sbin/ip link set virbr10-dummy address 52:54:00:1b:2c:3a

auto virbr10
iface virbr10 inet static
    bridge_ports virbr10-dummy
    bridge_stp on
    bridge_fd 2
    address 172.20.90.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0

#-----------------------------------------------------------------#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------#

## VIRBR122 ##

auto virbr122-dummy
iface virbr122-dummy inet manual
    pre-up /sbin/ip link add virbr122-dummy type dummy
    up /sbin/ip link set virbr122-dummy address 52:54:00:15:7b:9c

auto virbr122
iface virbr122 inet static
    bridge_ports virbr122-dummy
    bridge_stp on
    bridge_fd 2
    address 192.168.122.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0

#-----------------------------------------------------------------#
```

When I start only one of them it all works fine, but when i raise the other one the 1st one looses it's configuration as follows:

```
virbr10   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:1b:2c:3a  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:1540 (1.5 KB)

virbr122  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:15:7b:9c  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:46 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:8388 (8.3 KB)

virbr10-dummy Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:1b:2c:3a  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:711 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:52144 (52.1 KB)

virbr122-dummy Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:15:7b:9c  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1579 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:94742 (94.7 KB)
```

What am i doing wrong? (BTW I am setting up static virtual networks for KVM without using it's built-in methods - which are currently bugged).

FIRST EDIT:

I've changed the loading order of the interfaces to:

virbr10-dummy

virbr122-dummy

virbr10

virbr122

and it seems like it's working correctly now... still not fully persistent.

```
virbr10   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:1b:2d:3a  
          inet addr:172.20.90.1  Bcast:172.20.90.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:84 (84.0 B)

virbr122  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:15:7f:9c  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:84 (84.0 B)

virbr10-dummy Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:1b:2d:3a  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:1384 (1.3 KB)

virbr122-dummy Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:15:7f:9c  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:1384 (1.3 KB)
```

It's clearly some kind of loading order error/ timeout / bug I don't understand and clearly no one bothered to answer :'(